# MS Edge can't handle partial-content (206) response

Tags: http, microsoft-edge

I have a web app that sends a POST request in order to play a video stream. The stream response comes back as a 206 (partial-content) response.

For every video I can see that multiple requests are sent, and accordingly multiple 206 responses are received. It works as planned on Chrome browser (and even on IE11!).

The problem is that MS Edge receives 206 response only for the first time ,  the following response is always 200 (OK), and then it stops. It means that only the first part of the stream always arrives (and the video can not be played).

Comparing between http headers in Chrome and Edge, I have noticed that the only difference is that in Edge `cache-control: no-cache` header exists, while in Chrome it doesn't.

After some reading, I have reasons to believe that this problem somehow relates to [this](https://jakearchibald.com/2018/i-discovered-a-browser-bug/) article (Edge was lately updated, and a security issue, regarding partial content, was resolved). Is there any workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Edge are you using? About the cache-control, please check your code, when you send the http request, you could try to set the cache-control. I also try to create a sample, it seems that everything works well on my side (using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0), can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am using version 42.17134.1.0.
I am not sure that cache-control header is the reason for the problem. I mentioned it as the only difference between the headers.

Comment: Try to test [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/pq0kx3wL/) in the Microsoft edge browser, whether it works well, if it works well, the issue is not related to the Edge browser. can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, you could also capture the screenshot when using F12 developer tools to check the http request result.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your comment. I have tried this sample on Edge. It's not working.